# WMI PrinterStatus always 0

Tags: c#, printing, wmi

I want to check if the printer has a paper or not, for this I use WMI to pick up the printer and use `PrinterStatus`, the problem is that it always returns 0 ("Unknow"), and I don't understand the reason, my code is as follows:

```
public int ImpresoraStatus()
{
    var printerQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name = \"KPOS_80 Printer\"");
    foreach (var printer in printerQuery.Get())
    {
        int status = (int)printer["PrinterStatus"];
        return status;
    }

    return 404;
}
```

Any improvements or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue AFAIK. You probably need to try printing something first and then check the status.

See: [Not Able to Monitor Printers' States and Statuses](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86fdb42b-d0c7-4cb7-94ad-c1992eb7b89e/not-able-to-monitor-printers-states-and-statuses)